# difference between @rm and rm in makefile

Tags: makefile

In a few makefiles, I came across `@rm` syntax, vs `-rm` (ignore errors thrown by `rm`) and pure `rm`.

I'd like to know what's the difference.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry, So, should I simply close the issue? Or is there something specific I could do?

Comment: I just looked up the etiquette -- apparently I wasn't supposed to answer it, but instead just mark it as a duplicate (oops).   It will be closed automatically by the conveners with higher reps.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry, My mistake entirely. Thanks for not automatically downvoting the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@` tells make to not echo the recipe to output when it's run.

`-` tells make to ignore the return value of the recipe (assume it passes)

you can use a combination of both of these and `+`.   See the [Echoing](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html#Echoing) and [Errors](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html#Errors) 
 in the gnu make manual for details